# Which web font supports all languages?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a site which has fonts of all languages but most of the fonts don't support most of the languages other than English.

Is there any font that supports all the languages?

It will be OK if it is imported from Google fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most fonts support most human languages.

The problem with that page is that the text is encoded using UTF-8 but the page claims it is encoded using windows-1252.

Browsers are therefore following the wrong rules to work out what characters the 1s and 0s that make up the underlying HTML source mean.

When I override the encoding in my browser preferences and force it to parse as UTF-8, the text displays correctly (at least I assume it does, I don't understand the language).

Further reading:

- [Character encodings: Essential concepts](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/)
- [Character encodings](https://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php)
- [Handling character encodings in HTML and CSS (tutorial)](https://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/)
- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any font that supports all the languages?

Unicode is the unified table of characters. Some first characters are latin  literals (font subsets: latin and latin extended), then come other language literals and non-language signs, like pictograms. [Each language has its own table segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

How many languages supports a font is depending from how many font subsets and characters are created by the font designer.

The font containing the most characters (65.535) and supports **all** languages is [Noto](http://www.google.com/get/noto/).